# requests.exceptions.SSLError - Failing to use python module

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I am using the python module udemy-dl which i have installed via pypi.org/project/udemy-dl. When i run the script , i keep getting a SSL Error. I have looked through many questions on Stackoverflow and none of them have seemed to work. I get the following on my terminal:

```
[INFO-835] Downloading to: /Users/dev/the-complete-python-web-course-learn-by-building-8-apps

[INFO-107] Trying to log in ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/dev.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 837, in main
    udemy_dl(username, password, link, lecture_start, lecture_end, save_links, safe_file_names, just_list, output_dest)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 658, in udemy_dl
    login(username, password)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 109, in login
    csrf_token = get_csrf_token()
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 95, in get_csrf_token
    response = session.get('https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup')
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/udemy_dl/udemy_dl.py", line 66, in get
    return self.session.get(url, headers=self.headers)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/dev/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dev*emphasized text*/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)
```

I see that in adapters.py , is where the exception is raised :

```
def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        """Sends PreparedRequest object. Returns Response object.

        :param request: The :class:`PreparedRequest <PreparedRequest>` being sent.
        :param stream: (optional) Whether to stream the request content.
        :param timeout: (optional) How long to wait for the server to send
            data before giving up, as a float, or a :ref:`(connect timeout,
            read timeout) <timeouts>` tuple.
        :type timeout: float or tuple
        :param verify: (optional) Whether to verify SSL certificates.
        :param cert: (optional) Any user-provided SSL certificate to be trusted.
        :param proxies: (optional) The proxies dictionary to apply to the request.
        :rtype: requests.Response
        """

        conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)

        self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
        url = self.request_url(request, proxies)
        self.add_headers(request)

        chunked = not (request.body is None or 'Content-Length' in request.headers)

        if isinstance(timeout, tuple):
            try:
                connect, read = timeout
                timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=connect, read=read)
            except ValueError as e:
                # this may raise a string formatting error.
                err = ("Invalid timeout {0}. Pass a (connect, read) "
                       "timeout tuple, or a single float to set "
                       "both timeouts to the same value".format(timeout))
                raise ValueError(err)
        else:
            timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)

        try:
            if not chunked:
                resp = conn.urlopen(
                    method=request.method,
                    url=url,
                    body=request.body,
                    headers=request.headers,
                    redirect=False,
                    assert_same_host=False,
                    preload_content=False,
                    decode_content=False,
                    retries=self.max_retries,
                    timeout=timeout
                )

            # Send the request.
            else:
                if hasattr(conn, 'proxy_pool'):
                    conn = conn.proxy_pool

                low_conn = conn._get_conn(timeout=DEFAULT_POOL_TIMEOUT)

                try:
                    low_conn.putrequest(request.method,
                                        url,
                                        skip_accept_encoding=True)

                    for header, value in request.headers.items():
                        low_conn.putheader(header, value)

                    low_conn.endheaders()

                    for i in request.body:
                        low_conn.send(hex(len(i))[2:].encode('utf-8'))
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                        low_conn.send(i)
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                    low_conn.send(b'0\r\n\r\n')

                    # Receive the response from the server
                    try:
                        # For Python 2.7+ versions, use buffering of HTTP
                        # responses
                        r = low_conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
                    except TypeError:
                        # For compatibility with Python 2.6 versions and back
                        r = low_conn.getresponse()

                    resp = HTTPResponse.from_httplib(
                        r,
                        pool=conn,
                        connection=low_conn,
                        preload_content=False,
                        decode_content=False
                    )
                except:
                    # If we hit any problems here, clean up the connection.
                    # Then, reraise so that we can handle the actual exception.
                    low_conn.close()
                    raise

        except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
            raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

        except MaxRetryError as e:
            if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
                # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
                if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
                    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)

            if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):
                raise RetryError(e, request=request)

            if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):
                raise ProxyError(e, request=request)

            raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

        except ClosedPoolError as e:
            raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

        except _ProxyError as e:
            raise ProxyError(e)

        except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
            if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
                raise SSLError(e, request=request)
```

Answer (score 1):

The script you use will verify certain certificates with the main site and it allows connection only when the certificates are verified. Possible workaround.

1.) You need to download the certificates given by the website and pass the same to requests call `verify='path/to/ssl/certificate/'` (or)

2.) find the requests call in the script and set `verify=False`

Comment: the option verify is in adapters.py and sessions.py in many places. The error is raised in adapters.py. I have changed verify option to False but it still comes up with the same error